# Find an object with two matching property values and return another value from that object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with a data structure that looks like this:

```
const fieldArray = [{
    "angle": 32.0,
    "y": 0, 
    "x": 0 
}, { 
    "angle": 33.0,
    "y": 0, 
    "x": 10 
}, { 
    "angle": 34.0, 
    "y": 0, 
    "x": 20 
}, { 
    "angle": 35.0, 
    "y": 0, 
    "x": 30 
}, { 
    "angle": 36.0, 
    "y": 0, 
    "x": 40 
}] //the array I am using is much larger but follows this format
```

I have a known x and y value. I would like to write a function that finds the object with the matching x and y value and then returns the corresponding angle value. Here's what I have so far however after writing it I realize I need to use two for loops. Is there an easier way of doing this like using filter or array find for example?

```
function getFieldAngleValue (x, y) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i++){
            if(fieldArray[i].x == x && fieldArray[i].y == y ){
                let index = i
                break
            }
        }
        angle = fieldArray[index].angle;
        return angle;
},
```

Comment: You don't need two loops. What you have seems fine except you need to declare `index` outside the `for` loop so the code below can have access to it. Alternatively, you can just `return` inside the loop as soon as you find it.

Comment: You can use filter method with comparing statement to make simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `Array.find()` method, which makes your code more concise and easier to read. The `Array.find()` method returns the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no such element is found, it returns `undefined`.

Here's how you can rewrite your function using `Array.find()`:

```
function getFieldAngleValue(x, y) {
    const foundObject = fieldArray.find(obj => obj.x === x && obj.y === y);
    if (foundObject) {
        return foundObject.angle;
    } else {
        return undefined; // or any other value you want to return when no match is found
    }
}
```

This code snippet first uses the `Array.find()` method to search through the `fieldArray` for an object that matches the provided `x` and `y` values. If a matching object is found, it returns the corresponding `angle` value. If no match is found, it returns `undefined`, but you can customize the behavior for cases where no match is found.

This approach eliminates the need for nested loops and improves the readability of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response. Good idea to return a value (or potential error handling) if there's no match

Answer (score 0):

You can use array find method.
This is simpled function code.

```
function getFieldAngleValue (x, y) {
  searchedArray = fieldArray.find(a => a.x==x && a.y==y );
  return searchedArray.angle;
}
```